# How to go to certain part of android database

Tags: android

I am tying to do something if row 1 in the database is created and if its not created something else is done. its in a septate file called data.java
i want something like

if( data.ROW_ID !- 1 {
//do something
}
else{
//do this
}

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like this?

```
Cursor mCursor = mDatabase.query("tablename", null, "ROW_ID = 1", null, null, null, null);
if(mCursor.getCount() == 0){
   //do whatever
} else {
   //do different thing
}
```